# checking boolean value from Dictionary.

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a variable called attending being pulled from a JSON feed. After checking what class type the object is being interpreted as I NSLog this:

```
attending var type is: __NSCFBoolean
```

This is done using [varname class] to get the class type of the variable.

So I want to see if this is true or false.... so I write this code..:

```
if([[_events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"attending"] == YES){
```

However I cant compile it because it gives me a yellow text error saying this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this. Just to add the data in the feed looks like this:

```
    {
    attendees =         (
    );
    attending = 1;
    date = "2012-09-24 09:11:00";
    id = 504;
    lessonHTML = "somehtml.";
    name = "Sup";
    youtubeId = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1vb4cND3G0";
},
    {
    attendees =         (
    );
    attending = 1;
    date = "2012-09-24 09:11:00";
    id = 503;
    lessonHTML = "somehtml.";
    name = "Sup";
    youtubeId = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1vb4cND3G0";
},
    {
    attendees =         (
    );
    attending = 0;
    date = "2012-09-24 09:11:00";
    id = 508;
    lessonHTML = "somehtml.";
    name = "Sup";
    youtubeId = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1vb4cND3G0";
},
    {
    attendees =         (
    );
    attending = 1;
    date = "2012-09-24 09:11:00";
    id = 509;
    lessonHTML = "somehtml.";
    name = "Sup";
    youtubeId = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1vb4cND3G0";
},
    {
    attendees =         (
    );
    attending = 0;
    date = "2012-09-24 09:11:00";
    id = 505;
    lessonHTML = "somehtml.";
    name = "Sup";
    youtubeId = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1vb4cND3G0";
},
    {
    attendees =         (
    );
    attending = 1;
    date = "2012-09-24 09:11:00";
    id = 506;
    lessonHTML = "somehtml.";
    name = "Sup";
    youtubeId = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1vb4cND3G0";
},
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Boolean in dictionary and other container classes are encapsulated in `NSNumber` objects (see the `NSNumber` documentation for more info)

To extract the value you need to send the `boolValue` message to the object retrieved from the dictionary and compare it to YES/NO:

```
NSNumber* attendingObject = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"attending"];
if ([attendingObject boolValue] == YES)
{
    ...
}
```

**Read more about values and how they are encapsulated I collection classes [in the Apple documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html)**

Comment: you sir are a legend! My question is answered and my quest is complete. you gain 100 experience.

Comment: This is not correct because, `NSString* hello = @"hello";
    BOOL val = [hello boolValue];
    NSLog(@"%d", val);` will also return "0" - which is not correct. You need to use numberFormatter to truly get the value.

Answer (score 2):

a "`BOOL`" type is not an Objective C object but instead a C-style type.

It's stored in a dictionary as a "`NSNumber`" object.

So what you need to do instead of:

```
if([[_events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"attending"] == YES){
```

is something like this:

```
BOOL attending = NO; // assume NO to start with
NSDictionary * lessonDictionary = [_events objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
if(lessonDictionary)
{
     NSNumber * attendingObject = [lessonDictionary objectForKey: @"attending"];
     if(attendingObject)
     {
          attending = [attendingObject boolValue];
     }
}
```